# is it possible to highlight a specific line inside a paragraph tag using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, mysql

I have a huge text content saved in `mySQL Database`. Once the content is loaded in a `<p> tag`, by default, the first line should be highlighted. Is it possible to highlight the next line if a user scrolls down the paragraph scroll using `jQuery` in a single `<p> tag`. I know i can achive this using a lot of `<p>tags` inside a `<div>`. But taking care of the line breaks would be a tough job to do.

Thanks in advance.

[image: Scroll down causes the next line to be highlighted]

Comment: you cannot highlight a part of a text node content, you need to wrap it in an element and then add the styles to the wrapper element

Comment: can you provide how the html is generated?

Comment: Thanks for your reply @arunPJohny. I see. That means i have to wrap each line in a wrapper to do this. But taking care of line breaks would be hard. Is'nt it?

Comment: @DanielA.White, Let say, there is a `div` tag that contains a `<p>` tag and the text content.

Comment: @d_4dinkey Please post it.

Comment: First line can be done http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/css-better-paragraph/

Comment: @d_4dinkey Welcome :) Should i post it as answer ?

Comment: This won't work with user scrolling.

Comment: @TusharGupta... no. Its not a complete answer but it was a part in my whole problem. It is a 1/4th solution of my problem. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use van try jquery highligth plugin available on this site

http://bartaz.github.io/sandbox.js/jquery.highlight.html